# xml table data not showing after using xsl:include (using for each loop)

Tags: xml, xslt, include

Hello I am having a problem with xsl:import. when I try to import  a row of pictures as the header for the page the table data disappears from the other xsl file. if I take away the import it is fine.
any help would greatly appreciated.
here is the code I have so far.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:include href="topinclude.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="allIreland">
        <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dublin.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>



            <div id="firstYear">

            <table border="1">
            <caption>Dublin V Longford</caption>

                <tr>
                    <th>NUMBER</th>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>AGE</th>
                    <th>POSITION</th>
                    <th>CLUB</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each match="allIreland/year[@id='1976']/team/player[@id='2b'or@id='2b'or@id='2c'or@id='2d'or@id='2e'or@id='2g'or@id='2h'or@id='2j'or@id='2k'or@id='2l'or@id='2o'or@id='2q'or@id='2r'or@id='2s'or@id='2t'or@id='2u']">
                <tr> 
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="number"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="age"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="position"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="club"/></td>


                </tr>

           </table>

               <table border="1">
            <caption>Dublin V Laois</caption>

                <tr>
                    <th>NUMBER</th>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>AGE</th>
                    <th>POSITION</th>
                    <th>CLUB</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="allIreland/year[@id='1976']/team/player[@id='2a'or@id='2c'or@id='2d'or@id='2e'or@id='2q'or@id='2f'or@id='2g'or@id='2k'or@id='2l'or@id='2o'or@id='2p'or@id='2r'or@id='2s'or@id='2t'or@id='2u']">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="number"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="age"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="position"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="club"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
           </table>
               <table border="1">
            <caption>Dublin V Meath</caption>

                <tr>
                    <th>NUMBER</th>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>AGE</th>
                    <th>POSITION</th>
                    <th>CLUB</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="allIreland/year[@id='1976']/team/player[@id='2a'or@id='2c'or@id='2d'or@id='2e'or@id='2g'or@id='2q'or@id='2i'or@id='2k'or@id='2m'or@id='2o'or@id='2p'or@id='2r'or@id='2s'or@id='2t'or@id='2u']">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="number"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="age"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="position"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="club"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
           </table>
               <table border="1">
            <caption>Dublin V Galway</caption>

                <tr>
                    <th>NUMBER</th>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>AGE</th>
                    <th>POSITION</th>
                    <th>CLUB</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="allIreland/year[@id='1976']/team/player[@id='2a'or@id='2c'or@id='2d'or@id='2e'or@id='2f'or@id='2h'or@id='2j'or@id='2i'or@id='2k'or@id='2l'or@id='2o'or@id='2p'or@id='2r'or@id='2t'or@id='2v']">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="number"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="age"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="position"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="club"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
           </table>
               <table border="1">
            <caption>Dublin V Kerry</caption>

                <tr>
                    <th>NUMBER</th>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>AGE</th>
                    <th>POSITION</th>
                    <th>CLUB</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="allIreland/year[@id='1976']/team/player[@id='2a'or@id='2c'or@id='2d'or@id='2e'or@id='2f'or@id='2q'or@id='2i'or@id='2k'or@id='2l'or@id='2l'or@id='2o'or@id='2p'or@id='2r'or@id='2s'or@id='2t'or@id='2v']">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="number"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="age"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="position"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="club"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
           </table>
           </div>
          </body>
        </html>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet> 


    // and here is the include header

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/" priority="10">
    <html>
    <head><title>Header</title></head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
    <img src="gaa1.jpg"/>
    <img src="gaa2.jpg"/>
      <img src="gaa1.jpg"/>
      <img src="gaa2.jpg"/>
      <img src="gaa1.jpg"/>
      </div>

    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Your first sample has nested `xsl:template`s, that is not allowed so I don't think the include is the problem.

Comment: That wasn't supposed to be there i put it there to see if it would change anything. I forgot to take it out before I uploaded it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that both XSLTs - the main template and the included `topinclude.xsl` - generates full HTML pages with html start / end tags, header, body etc., so the result would be an html page with the header `<div>` from the topinclude.xsl containing a second html-page generated by the including template in the `<body>`.
As the topinclude.xsl is included on top, you should move the `<head>` of the main template (because of the dublin.css include) to `topinclude.xsl` and remove the `<html>`, `<body>` and `<head>` tags from the including template.